# c++ wchar array to c#

Tags: c#, c++, language-comparisons

I have no knowledge of C++ and I have to cenvert some code to C#. I've managed to do some bits but I don't really understand how to convert a few lines so I'm here asking for help.

This is the C++ code:

```
            WCHAR wsSerial[MAX_PATH]={'\0'};
            WCHAR wsS2[MAX_PATH]={'\0'};

            wcscpy_s(wsSerial, MAX_PATH, m_strSerial);
            wcscpy_s(wsS2,MAX_PATH,wsSerial+8);
            wsS2[8]=NULL;
            ULONG ulCode2 = wcstoul(wsS2, NULL,10);
```

This is what I have in C#:

```
        string wsSerial;
        string wsS2;

        wsSerial = mSerial; //an external input
        wsS2 = wsSerial + 8;
        wsS2= wsSerial.Substring(0, 8);
        long ulCode2 = long.Parse(wsS2);
```

So I have two questions:

1. wsSerial is an array in C++ but I don't need an array for this in C#, do I? I mean, all it does is store a large number which is later converted into a numeric value, right?
2. What exactly does this do? wcscpy_s(wsS2,MAX_PATH,wsSerial+8). The + 8 throws me off.

Answer (score 2):

In C a string is simply a contiguous area containing a "string" of characters, terminated by a special character. In other words, an array of `char`. (Or `wchar_t` for wide-character strings.)

In C# (and C++) this is not needed as it has its own special `string` type, which handles the array-stuff behind the scenes.

---

Regarding the `+8` thing, it simply skips the first eight characters of `wsSerial` when copying. To understand this, you should read about "pointer arithmetic".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're almost all the way there, but the first argument in the call to

```
wsSerial.Substring()
```

should be 8, the second should be MAX_PATH minus 8.

Comment: Actually, in the C code the OP is terminating that after 8 character, so the length should be 8.

Comment: No, the original is adding 8 to the source pointer, so starting the copy 8 chars in.

Comment: Yes, but look at the next source line.

Comment: Blimey.  So we're helping to transcribe what looks suspiciously like broken code!

Answer (score 1):

It's like this:

```
string wsSerial = mSerial;
string wsS2 = wsSerial.Substring(8, 8);
long ulCode2 = long.Parse(wsS2);
```